# How can i connect MySQL database with WordPress website

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How can i connect a database with tables that have information with WordPress website?

I tried to put database name , password, username , but created new tables on my database, I want to use the tables that are already in my database not a new ones

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more info on what you are doing,

the new tables you talk about are they in created in the same database?

you could try editing the wp-config.php directly, instead of going thru the web install.

Just edit the database settings, leave the rest.
Ensure you get the table prefix right,

```
$table_prefix = 'wp_';
```

this should match the string your existing tables start with.

hope this helps!